# What is wrong with my code to find the prime factors of a number?

Tags: python

What is wrong with this code to find the primes of a number and store them in a list?

```
def primes(num):
    res = num
    i = 2
    z = []
    while res != 1:
        if num%i == 0:
            z.append(i)
            res = num/i
        else:
            i += 1
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? You probably want integer division which is `//`

Comment: python 2 but the thing is it doesn't terminate when i call primes(4) it keeps adding 2 to the list of primes

Comment: @NikolasPitsillos `res = num/i` should be `res = res/i`

Comment: Oh thank you.  Hahah I guess time I should get a rest after after a long flight. Thank you appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

if `num=4` and `i=2` you got an infinite loop, cause "i" and "res" never changes ...

It's python compliant, but your algorithm is not good.

Try `res = res/i`.

Comment: Do you know a better one?